# Is there a Masterplan-like tool for 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, tools, gm-preparation

I'm looking for a tool like [Masterplan](http://web.archive.org/web/20160720091339/http://masterplan.habitualindolence.net:80/) or something near, but for a 3.5 / Pathfinder d20 game.

*I don't mind if you know of something better ;)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know of no tool that is actively supported that comes close to Masterplan for 3.5/Pathfinder/D20 style games.  There are or were a number of tools that could be used in combination to do some of it.

[PCGen](http://pcgen.sourceforge.net/01_overview.php) is a good solid tool for some parts of what you are looking for.  There are data files that can be loaded into it that are for D&D (3E, 3.5E, 4E), d20 Modern, and Pathfinder.  To get actual published/copywrited material you will need to add it manually your self.  This is a tool I have used and liked but it does not do everything Masteplan does.

RPTools has a suite of tools that you can use. [RPTools Website](http://www.rptools.net/index.php?page=tools)  They have a tool for mapping, initiative, character management, dice rolling and token making (useful for the maps).

DM Secretary by [Occult Entertainment](http://occultentertainment.50webs.com/index.html) is useful for tracking campaign data.  It is not actively being update as far as I can tell, (last update Feb. 2010) but you can still get it.  They also offer a RPG Suite, but I don't know much about it.  It is still available for download.

These are the ones that have been prominent in the past and are still availble.  There are also a number of mapping tools/generators that are not supported as far as I can tell but still available for download. Dungeon Crafter, Interactive Dungeon, Tile Mapper, Creator System 2, AutoRealm and Dungeon Maker are some of these that I know and are still out there.  Just search on the name and their sites will come up.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it would be useful for you to look at my [Excel Spreadsheet](http://rroleplaying.blogspot.com/2012/08/excel-combat-manager-worksheet.html). It's what I use for all my notes and combat management, and [I even use it to draw maps](http://rroleplaying.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-draw-dungeon-with-excel.html).

[image: an example of making maps in excel]

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you take a look at [combatmanager](http://www.combatmanager.com).  The program is used to run combats, but also has rules, spells, feats, etc. It's not exactly like Masterplan but it's an incredible piece of software and it's designed for Pathfinder!

Answer (score 1):

Check out Wolf Lair Development, the makers of HeroLab and ArmyBuilder.  They are releasing soon a program designed specifically for this called [RealmWorks](http://wolflair.com/index.php?context=realm_works).